# Access Array record and normal record from JSON

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016-express

I am new to handling json records. I have a json record as follows:

```
{"responseobj":{"ResponseCode":"0","ResponseDesc":"Success"},
    "objDropdown":[{"Master_id":0,"ID":"en","Value":"English","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"fr","Value":"français","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"it","Value":"italiano","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"pt","Value":"Português","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"es","Value":"español","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"de","Value":"Deutsch","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"nl","Value":"Nederlands","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
      ]}'
```

Please teach me how to get a record from this.

Comment: See the [`OPENJSON` reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql) for syntax and examples you can adapt for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with OpenJSON() - SQL server 2016 and up:

```
DECLARE @json VARCHAR(4000);

SET @json
    = '{"responseobj":{"ResponseCode":"0","ResponseDesc":"Success"},
    "objDropdown":[{"Master_id":0,"ID":"en","Value":"English","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"fr","Value":"français","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"it","Value":"italiano","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"pt","Value":"Português","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"es","Value":"español","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"de","Value":"Deutsch","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
        ,{"Master_id":0,"ID":"nl","Value":"Nederlands","Selected":false,"IsActive":false,"Description":null,"TopupId":0,"TopupAmount":0}
      ]}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.objDropdown')
    WITH
    (
        Master_id INT '$.Master_id',
        ID VARCHAR(5) '$.ID',
        [Value] NVARCHAR(50) '$.Value',
        Selected BIT '$.Selected',
        IsActive BIT '$.IsActive',
        [Description] NVARCHAR(4000) '$.Description',
        TopupId INT '$.TopupId',
        TopupAmount INT '$.TopupAmount'
    );
```

EDIT: Getting responseobj is even simpler:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.responseobj');
```

Comment: but i need value from "responseobj" also.

Comment: @Shaul, then you can simply follow the syntax and edit it to get what you need. Why would you expect me to write all of your code? Would you like me to write your project too? Anyway edited for you.

Comment: @Shahul, for whatever it is instead of reading and trying the docs you shouldn't expect others to type it to the last dot for you. You can't learn without trying yourself.